# How to write modulo relation in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to type the expression below:

[image]

From latex math symbols I searched for on the web, I tried:

```
$(m^k)^u \equiv m \mod{pq}$
```

but the 'mod' won't show up. 
So I have again tried without the curly brackets:

```
$(m^k)^u \equiv m \mod pq$
```

but this, too, doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you load `amsmath` (or `mathtools`, which loads i? It defines four commands: `\pmod{n}` (with parentheses), the variant `\pod{n}`, and  `\mod{n}` (spaced  by 1 quad) and the variant `\bmod{n}` (closer).

Comment: I see thanks! Is adding \usepackage{amsmath} to my code enough to load the package? I've added the above, but commands like \square or \blacksquare are still not showing up

Comment: These commands are in `amssymb`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a comment of excellent user Bernard I have provide to add a code and also with `\pod{pq}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (m^k)^u &\equiv m \mod{pq}\\
  (m^k)^u &\equiv m \pmod{pq} \\
  (m^k)^u &\equiv m \bmod pq\\
  (m^k)^u &\equiv m \pod{pq}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) You might add  `\pod{pq}` to be complete.

Comment: Thank lot lot Bernard (and others) and look, I've spied you among the mathematicians :-).

Comment: Spied me ?!!! Concerning `\pod`, you misunderstood me: you don't have to add `mod` by hand. It is designed for the short notation  `≡ m (pq)`.

Comment: Done! When there are no LaTeX questions that interest me, I go to mathematicians. At that site I signed up and saw your excellent reputation. In that sense, I spied on you because you had a question raised to me. :-) Thanks always for everything. I have not used congruence classes for at least 23 years. Do not put mod is the same thing to write $GCD (m, n) = (m, n)$ and as you could notice English I learn it slowly thanks to you of the site.

Comment: I agree the \pod notation can be ambiguous – generally it seems to be used in contexts with no ambiguity, and if it has to be used  repeatedly.

Comment: `\bmod` (for binary mod) should be used instead of `\;\mathrm{mod}\;`